# Prevent ajax returning fail, for frequently request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with ajax to get some data. The problem is ajax request was coming from hovering a button so that can be very easily to spam the request that may lead to fail `error 404 or error 500`. This is my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
          url: location.origin+'/getcat',
          data : {
                   't': id
                 },
          success: function(){ alert("I'm handsome"); }
});
```

The question is how to prevent this spam request?

Comment: You will want to implement a debounce feature,.. lodash has a simple function -> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#debounce

Answer (score 0):

You could make it with `setTimeout()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer;
var delay = 1000;
    $("p").hover(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Requesting")
        $.ajax({
                  url: location.origin+'/getcat',
                  data : {
                           't': id
                         },
                  success: function(data){ 
                        alert('Im handsome'); 
                      }
                  });
        }, delay);
        }, function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log("Canceled request")
    });
});
```

Comment: where is clearTimeout() coming from? Is it default function or custom ? @SilverSurfer

Comment: It is a javascript method

Comment: You seem to cancelling the request when user unhover the element. Are we assuming that the user will keep the cursor locked under that element till the user gets the response?

Comment: @Myrealname Updated answer you dont need unbind nothing, cause only get fires one time, try my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.one()` which will only use the event handler once. Then you can execute that `.one()` again, when a cool-down period has expired.

```js
(function enableRequests() {
    console.log("listening for next mouse move");
    $('#spn').one("mousemove", function() {
        console.log("launching request, and cooling down for 5 seconds");
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
            success: function () { console.log('response from server') }
        });
        setTimeout(enableRequests, 5000); // 5 second cooldown period
    });
})(); // execute immediately
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="spn">Hover here</span>
```